# Komma- und Semikolonzeichensetzung

Tags: punctuation

Wie müssen das Komma und das Semikolon benutzt werden?

Ich suche täglich Wörter im [DUDEN Wörterbuch](https://www.duden.de). Ab und zu finde ich eine Bedeutungsangabe mit Semikolon. Außerdem finde ich Kommata, die nicht unter den Bedinungen benutzt werden, die unten beschrieben sind:

- Um eine Liste von Personen oder Sachen zu trennen
- Um den Hauptsatz und Nebensatz zu trennen

Zum Beispiel:
Die Bedeutung des Worts [sachgerecht](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/sachgerecht): "der Sache, den in der Sache begründeten Anforderungen gerecht werdend; sachgemäß".

Answer (score 4):

§ 80 des [amtlichen Regelwerks](https://www.rechtschreibrat.com/DOX/rfdr_Regeln_2016_redigiert_2018.pdf) des Rats für deutsche Rechtschreibung lautet:

> Mit dem Semikolon kann man gleichrangige (nebengeordnete) Teilsätze oder Wortgruppen voneinander abgrenzen. Mit dem Semikolon drückt man  einen höheren Grad der Abgrenzung aus als mit dem Komma und einen geringeren Grad der Abgrenzung als  mit dem Punkt.

Das Regelwerk gibt für *(1) gleichrangige, vor allem auch längere Hauptsätze (mit Nebensatz)* folgendes Beispiel:

> Im Hausflur war es  still; ich drückte erwartungsvoll auf die  Klingel.

Richtig sind allerdings auch:

> Im Hausflur war es still, ich drückte erwartungsvoll auf die Klingel.
>
> Im Hausflur war es still. Ich drückte erwartungsvoll auf die Klingel.

(Wenn man so will, könnte man hier auch noch den Gedankenstrich erwähnen, aber machen wir es nicht komplizierter als es muss.)

Das Semikolon ist, wie es in § 80 steht, eine Zwischenstufe zwischen Punkt und Komma. Der Unterschied ist subtil und schwankt zwischen dem, was man ausdrücken will, und persönlichem Geschmack. Ich würde auch die Behauptung aufstellen wollen, dass die meisten deutschen Muttersprachler das Semikolon nie benutzen (solange sie nicht im IT-Umfeld arbeiten) und im Zweifel eher das Komma als das Semikolon benutzen würden.

Der Duden in deinem Beispiel nutzt das Semikolon, um *(2) gleichrangige Wortgruppen gleicher Struktur in Aufzählungen* zu kennzeichnen.

> Unser Proviant bestand aus gedörrtem Fleisch, Speck und Rauchschinken; Ei- und Milchpulver; Reis, Nudeln und Grieß.

Hier hat man drei Gruppen: Fleisch - Tiererzeugnisse - Beilage, kann also entsprechend trennen. Muss man aber nicht. Richtig ist auch:

> Unser  Proviant  bestand  aus  gedörrtem  Fleisch,  Speck  und  Rauchschinken, Ei- und Milchpulver, Reis, Nudeln und Grieß.

In dem Beispiel *der Sache, den in der Sache begründeten Anforderungen gerecht werdend; sachgemäß* werden Synonymgruppen getrennt, bzw. Satzbaualternativen. Ein Komma würde hier eher verwirren, bzw. würde den Inhalt verfremden. Dazu sei auch gesagt, dass diese Beispiele oft bewusst knapp gehalten werden.

Aus dieser knappen Wiedergabe ergibt sich auch das Komma in *der Sache, den in der Sache begründeten Anforderungen gerecht werdend*. Man hat hier sozusagen zwei Beispiele:

> - der Sache gerecht werdend
> - den in der Sache begründeten Anforderungen gerecht werdend

Answer (score 1):

Das lässt sich pauschal nicht sagen. Wir zum Beispiel haben in der Schule überhaupt nie etwas über Strichpunkte gehört, und so geht es den meisten wahrscheinlich. Ich würde mir das in der Fachliteratur meines Vertrauens durchlesen.

Generell werden Semikola selten verwendet; wenn du also noch Deutsch lernst, wird es wahrscheinlich besser sein, darauf zu verzichten. Es ist so, dass sie dann verwendet werden, wenn zwei Sätze ihrer Bedeutung nach so eng zusammengehören, dass ein Punkt eine zu starke Trennung wäre. Die Sätze müssen aber beide mehr oder weniger für sich stehen können. Nach einem Strickpunkt kann zum Beispiel (generell) nicht "dass" oder "weil" stehen. Ich persönlich verwende auch gerne ein Semikolon, wenn ich Listen schreibe; ähnliche Dinge können so gruppiert werden. Zum Beispiel: "Einzukaufen sind: Bananen, Äpfel, Birnen; Toilettenpapier, Seife und Shampoo; Nudeln und Tomatensugo."